# SQLAlchemy equivalent to select_related and prefetch_related with nested relations

Tags: python, django-models, sqlalchemy

This query with Django ORM takes 0.03 seconds:

```
entry = ModelA.objects.select_related(
            'modelB',
            'modelC',
        ).prefetch_related(
            'modelB__modelD',
            'modelE',
            'modelE__modelF',
            'modelE__modelF__modelG',
            'modelE__modelF__modelG__modelH1',
            'modelE__modelF__modelG__modelH2',
            'modelE__modelF__modelG__modelH3',
            'modelE__modelF__modelI',
            'modelE__modelF__modelJ',
        ).get(id=1)
```

The equivalent I could come up with in SQLAlchemy takes 0.12 seconds*:

```
entry = session.query(ModelA) \
        .options(joinedload(ModelA.modelB).joinedload(ModelB.modelD)) \
        .options(subqueryload(ModelA.modelE).subqueryload(ModelE.modelF)
                .subqueryload(ModelF.modelG).subqueryload('*')) \
        .options(subqueryload(ModelA.modelE).subqueryload(ModelE.modelF)
                .subqueryload(ModelF.modelI)) \
        .options(subqueryload(ModelA.modelE).subqueryload(ModelE.modelF)
                .subqueryload(ModelF.modelJ)) \
        .filter(ModelA.id = 1) \
        .first()
```

*I realized that in Django I query modelC that I don't really need.

- How can I replace `subqueryload('*')` with the desired multiple relations to the same table through the fields `modelH1`, `modelH2` and `modelH3`?
- When I ham iterating over `ModelE` instances, the reference to to `ModelA` triggers a new query in sqlAlchemy, while in the Django ORM it gets automatically populated. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Please post your model definitions.

Comment: From my (very limited) understanding of Django, these 2 don't look equivalent. For example in the Django version you use prefetch loading to get ModelD's related through ModelB, but in your SQLA version you use joinedload, or in other words possibly you have ModelA left join ModelB left join ModelD, which depending on your data and database can be much more inefficient.

Comment: Did you figure this out? The comments here aren't very helpful, and I'm also curious as to what the answer is!